# Jquery - How do I find nonEmpty field from several selectors, send value to another field

Tags: jquery

Help please, I am not quite sure how to approach this one:
I have an app where the client has several sections which contain several fields.  Sometimes the same field appears.  For example, "**quantity**" or "**color**" may appear in three, four or more sections.

When the web form is submitted, the value sent to the other end is empty because the next qty field, which is empty, will overwrite the value, thus producing an empty/null value on the other end. [there is only one quantity field on the other end]

Because of the structure of this app, which they want to maintain,  I want a clear cut way of saying/do the following using jquery:

get fields #quantityOne,#quantityTwo,#quantityThree, determine which one has a value in it, take that value and place it in hidden field finalQty.

Could someone show me how to accomplish this please?

**Adding one note for clarification:**

> The user would only be filling out ONE of the sections, thus only one
>   of the qty fields. So if I put 555 in qtyField #1, then 555 should be
>   copied to finalQty, if I put 35 in qtyField #2, then 35 should be
>   copied to finalQty

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/4ruh2/)

**html/jquery:**

```
<fieldset id="sectionOne" name="sectionOne">
<legend class='legendHdrs' >Section One</legend>
Name: <input type="text" name="nameOne" id="nameOne" class="name" /><br />
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantityOne" id="quantityOne" class="quantity"/>
    </fieldset><br /><br />

<fieldset id="sectionTwo">
<legend>Section Two</legend>
Name: <input type="text" name="nameTwo" id="nameTwo" class="name" /><br />
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantityTwo" id="quantityTwo" class="quantity"/>
</fieldset><br /><br />

<fieldset  id="sectionThree">
<legend>Section Three</legend>
Name: <input type="text" name="nameThree" id="nameThree" class="name" /><br />
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantityThree" id="quantityThree" class="quantity"/>
</fieldset>
<hr>

Final Qty: <input type="text" name="finalQty" id="finalQty" class="finalQty"/>
 <input type="button" value="Add Qty" id="addQty">
</form>​

    $(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#addQty').on('click', function()
            {
            var holdval;
        $('#quantityOne,#quantityTwo,#quantityThree').each(function() 
                    {
                        if($(this).val() !== '')
                            {
                                holdval = $(this).val() 
                            }
                    });
        $('#finalQty').val(holdval);
            });

 });
```

Comment: Is it possible for more than one to be filled?

Comment: Hi Mathletics - no in the actual app, it will be an either/or situation. The user would only be filling out ONE of the sections, thus only one of the qty field.  So if I put 555 in qtyField #1, then 555 should be copied to finalQty, if I put 35 in qtyField #2, then 35 should be copied to finalQty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### According to edit

```
$('#addQty').on('click', function(){
       $('.quantity').each(function(){
            var val = $.trim( this.value );
            if(val){
                $('#finalQty')val(val);
                break;
            } 
        });
    });
```

Comment: @user1176783 I think you want something this. If you have any other modification then comment me.

Comment: Ya this works, I just posted my response before I saw this one.  I would just change the jquery selector to the class instead of each id of each node.

Comment: The first one is more down the line of what I really want, but here is the snag.  It works when I add a value to the first quantity field, but if I add a value to the second or third, that value is not copied into the finalQty field.

Comment: So you don't want a sum of the values you just want them like comma delimited? Then just make a string and as you loop through the values add them to the string (if they aren't empty) then when your done looping place that string value in your hidden field.

Comment: Ahhh, no not the sum, I want the value that is placed in the quantity field copied to the finalQty field, because it will be an either/or situation.  The user would only be filling out ONE of the sections, so if I put 555 in qtyField #1, then 555 should be copied to finalQty, if I put 35 in qtyField #2, then 35 should be copied to finalQty.

Comment: I updated the jquery code above and jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/4ruh2/).  I thought this would work.  It checks each field, if one is not empty, sends that value to variable, then at the end, sends the contents of that var to the finalQty field, but it is not working.  Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: @user1176783 now, check my update and comment if you need anything more

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to use the class and loop through that instead of listing the id of each node in the jquery selector.

```
  $('#addQty').on('click', function(){
        $.each($('.quantity'), function(){
            if($(this).val() !== ''){
                //do something
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I do like using the class when possible, but this app doesn't have them either 'at all' or 'correctly', so for now, I just want an easy fix, so they can grab the id's, drop them in and let jquery do the rest.

Comment: I updated the jquery code above and jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/4ruh2/).  I thought this would work.  It checks each field, if one is not empty, sends that value to variable, then at the end, sends the contents of that var to the finalQty field, but it is not working.  Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: I updated you jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ruh2/8/). You just needed to define holdVal outside of the each loop.